# DotNet 5.0 Core MVC - using with JsonPatchDocument - PATCH not working - 404 not found

Tags: json, .net, model-view-controller, .net-core, patch

I am using the newly released Dotnet 5.0 project (MVC project):

`dotnet new mvc`

Inside .csproj file:  `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="5.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have tried to test using the tutorial, but doesn't work.
[ASP Net Core API - Partial Update using HTTP Patch](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-web-api/asp-net-core-api-how-to-perform-partial-update-using-http-patch)

```
// Startup.cs  
    // Added .AddNewtonsoftJson() extension method from NewtonsoftJsonMvcBuilderExtensions

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
            // .... truncated ....
            
            // Add custom route for /api

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "api",
                    pattern: "api/{controller=VideoGame}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });

        }
```

```
// VideoGame.cs
public partial class VideoGame
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
 
    public virtual string Publisher { get; set; }
 
    public virtual DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
 
    public VideoGame(int id, string title, string publisher, DateTime? releaseDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Publisher = publisher;
        ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
}
```

**As already mentioned the template does not work, so I added some extra controller actions `[HttpGet] Index()` and `[HttpGet] Patch()`: ** and *leaving the `[HttpPatch] Patch()` method unchanged as tutorial*

```
// VideoGameController.cs
using Test_JSON_Patch.Classes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;

// Removed this route - because it didn't work at all (even without adding a custom route) 
// [Route("api/video-game")]
// So current resolves to https://localhost/api/VideoGame/Index
public class VideoGameController : Controller
{
    IList<VideoGame> VideoGames { get; set; }
 
    public VideoGameController()
    {
        VideoGames = new List<VideoGame>();
 
        VideoGames.Add(new VideoGame(1, "Call of Duty: Warzone", "Activision", new System.DateTime(2020, 3, 10)));
        VideoGames.Add(new VideoGame(2, "Friday the 13th: The Game", "Gun Media", new System.DateTime(2017, 5, 26)));
        VideoGames.Add(new VideoGame(3, "DOOM Eternal", "Bethesda", new System.DateTime(2020, 3, 20)));
    }
 
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(){
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Patch(){
        // Just using View from home page to confirm Patch GET
        ViewBag.DataTest = "Patch Home Page";
        return View("Index");
    }
    
    [HttpPatch("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<VideoGame> patchEntity)
    {
        var entity = VideoGames.FirstOrDefault(videoGame => videoGame.Id == id);
 
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
 
        patchEntity.ApplyTo(entity, ModelState); // Must have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson installed
        
        return Ok(entity);
    } 
}
```

Testing using the following JSON as example shown:  (using PATCH method in POSTMAN)

```
// PATCH method using POSTMAN and raw body: - tried |BOTH| array and single object syntax
https://localhost:5001/api/VideoGame/Patch/id/2
[
    {
        "value": "Friday the 13th",
        "path": "/title",
        "op": "replace"
    }
]
```

This returns `404 Not Found` ....

Notes about the path *https://localhost:5001/api/VideoGame/...*:

- Navigating to normal MVC *[HttpGet]* action methods `Index` and `Patch` actually returns the Views as expected, this confirms the path can be resolved.
- Removing the /id argument from *[HttpPatch] Patch()* method will return `405 Method Not Allowed` - which means my other method [HttpGet] Patch() then executes, and fails because PATCH is not allowed.
- So, PATCH method does not work, or cannot be resolved to the path.

What am I missing? Or can't I use 'MVC actions' and 'Patch API actions' in the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve using the PATCH updates, I can indeed use it one the same project, *I am using a Dotnet MVC project*.

The tutorial linked in my question does not work with current versions of Dotnet Core 3x or the new Dotnet 5.0, but it just needs a slight update.

Almost everything in my question was correct, with some slight changes after doing different tests.

The necessary pieces:

Add these two libraries using Nuget etc:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch`
- **The .proj / solution file**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="5.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

- **Startup.cs**

  - *Do not add new `.MapControllerRoute()` route paths for the api*, *this does not seem to work correctly with JsonPatch*
  - Make sure that `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is referenced, the static class `NewtonsoftJsonMvcBuilderExtensions`
  - Add `AddNewtonsoftJson()` to services:  (The `IMvcBuilder` extended)

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }
```

- **Your controller**:

Take note the difference between the tutorial Route and the Route that eventually worked.  `ApiController` attribute is optional.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;

namespace X{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class VideoGameController : Controller

        [HttpPatch("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<VideoGame> patchEntity)
        {
            var entity = VideoGames.FirstOrDefault(videoGame => videoGame.Id == id);
    
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
    
            patchEntity.ApplyTo(entity, ModelState); // Must have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson installed
            
            return Ok(entity);
        }
}
```

### Troubleshooting

*Firstly:* Do not add new `.MapControllerRoute()` route paths for the api, *this does not seem to work correctly with JsonPatch*

> Error 405 Method Not allowed.

- Make sure your Route is exactly as here in the Controller, route in Startup.cs does not seem to work with JsonPatch.
- Also make sure that you *have JSON as content-type*

> Error 415 "Unsupported Media Type"

- Your content-type is not set as JSON.

> The `patchEntity` collection is empty, but the response is `200` success (appears that is working, but no patch happened on object.

- I found that if the `AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension method is not added, the collection will be empty, giving a successful request but no updates.